# ef core 2.0 search multiple columns with contains filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

Assume entity, `Patient` exists in the context, which has been generated using the database-first approach, so I can not modify the database.

```
public class Patient
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }
   public string Forename { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to filter patients by name e.g. first name or last name or full name. I currently have the following query:

```
await query
         .Where(p => p.Forename != null && p.Forename.ToLower().Contains(filter) ||
                     p.Surname != null && p.Surname.ToLower().Contains(filter))
         .ToListAsync();
```

This obviously only checks the forename/surname columns individually. If the filter is the full name, it does not work.

I tried string interpolation within the where clause to apply the contains filter against the combination of forename and surname but it is not supported in ef core and executes locally. Since there are over a million patients in the database, executing the query locally in the application is not an option and must be done in the database (it takes over a minute for a search).

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: An elegant solution: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5506/167333

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interpolation can't be translated by EF.

Just use the '+' operator to concatenate the strings like below:

```
await query
     .Where(p => p.Forename.ToLower().Contains(filter) ||
                 p.Surname.ToLower().Contains(filter)) || 
                 (p.Forename + " " + p.Surname).ToLower().Contains(filter))
     .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Only below should solve the purpose. Just for speed purpose

await query
     .Where(p => 
                 (p.Forename + " " + p.Surname).ToLower().Contains(filter))
     .ToListAsync();