# EF Core 5 Contains with several columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two models that look something like this:

```
public class Filter
{
    public string Key {get;set;}
    public Guid ProgramId {get;set;}
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Key {get;set;}
    public Guid ProgramId {get;set;}
}
```

I want to fetch all `MyEntity` where `Key` and `ProgramId` are represented in a list at least once. The combination of `Key` and `ProgramId` is crucial, since both `Key` and `ProgramId` can exist in different `Filter`s in different coalitions. Therefore both `Key` and `ProgramId` must be a match.

My code looks something like this:

```
// Initiation of filters is obviously different, but it could look something like this
var filters = new []
{
    new Filter { Key = "1", ProgramId = Guid.NewGuid() },
    new Filter { Key = "2", ProgramId = Guid.NewGuid() }
}
```

I have tried the following. All examples gives the result I want if they are evaluated in-memory, but no one can be executed/translated as SQL.

Alt 1. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046927/ef-core-2-0-search-multiple-columns-with-contains-filter):

```
var concatFilters = filters.Select(x => x.Key + "_" + x.ProgramId).ToArray();
var result = myContext.MyTable.Where(x => concatFilters.Contains(x.Key + "_" +  x.ProgramId));
// It gives: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar.
```

Alt 2:

```
var filterPrograms = filters.Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, ProgramId = x.ProgramId }).ToArray();  
var query = myContext.MyTable.Where(x => filterPrograms.Contains( new { Key = x.Key, ProgramId = x.ProgramId} ));
// It cannot be translated.
```

Alt 3:

```
var query = myContext.MyTable.Where(x => filters.Any(y => y.Key == x.Key && y.ProgramId == x.ProgramId));
// It cannot be translated.
```

I use paging and need this to be evaluated in SQL for my paging to work correctly. I'm running .NET 5 with EF Core 5.0.6.  Any ideas?

Comment: I did this recently using a custom expression which basicly made a huge `(y.Key == x.Key && y.ProgramId == x.ProgramId) OR (y.Key == x.Key && y.ProgramId == x.ProgramId)` statement for each of the items I wanted to check (in your case `filters`). I don't have the time to write up a proper answer right now but that might give you an idea at least.

Comment: the most correct looks like Alt 1. question have you tired... 
`var result = myContext.MyTable.Where(x => concatFilters.Contains(x.Key + "_" +  x.ProgramId.ToString()));` or `var result = myContext.MyTable.Where(x => concatFilters.Contains((x.Key + "_" +  x.ProgramId.ToString())));`

Comment: also try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257251/convert-int-to-string-in-linq-for-searching which would be like `concatFilters.Contains(x.Key + "_" +  (string)x.ProgramId));` or `concatFilters.Contains(x.Key + "_" +  SqlFunctions.StringConvert(x.ProgramId)));`

one of those should be the answer... let me know which one and i will post as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67666649/lambda-linq-with-contains-criteria-for-multiple-keywords/67666993#67666993) my answer for extension method `FilterByItems`. Then you can do the following:

```cs
var filters = new []
{
    new Filter { Key = "1", ProgramId = Guid.NewGuid() },
    new Filter { Key = "2", ProgramId = Guid.NewGuid() }
};

var result = myContext.MyTable
    .FilterByItems(filters, (x, f) => x.Key == f.Key && x.ProgramId == f.ProgramId, true);
```

Comment: Works great. It even renders some descent looking SQL. Thanks.